# Can't find symbol @android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have defined a theme in `values/themes.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
    </style>
</resources>
```

and in my `AndroidManifest.xml` I have:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

The code is compiled and I see the proper result, but IDE tells me it cannot resolve symbol `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar`. Please advice why.

Comment: What Android Platform version do you use in this module dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, try to change the android compiling libraries to the 3.2 Android version. It will let you use this themes and should be compatible with previous versions.
Be careful with the API you use. Despite of this you can set your minSdkVersion to 8.

Answer (score 0):

Your `minSdkVersion` is too low for the Holo theme. The Holo theme is only available on SDK 11 (Honeycomb) and later. You may want to look at [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com). Since it looks like you're not using the action bar, you could also put separate `themes.xml` files in `values` and `values-v11`.

Comment: Yes, I didn't say, but I defined separate resource (values-v11) for this and a default one with @android:style/Theme